# Angular2 child component submit in edit form not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component, and inside that i have a child component, when i click on edit, it shows edit form properly and the previous data of child component (select dropdown) is shown, but now if i want to not select another option of that dropdown (child component) and submit the form to update the data, form submitted but that dropdown is posted as empty. But if click on dropdown and select another option, or the previous one, then submit is working properly.

`parent.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { JobsService } from '../jobs.service';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'job-edit',
  templateUrl: './parent.template.html',
  providers: [JobsService],
})

export class JobEditComponent {
  job: any = {};
  errorMessage: string;
  paramsObserver: any;
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  expireDate;
  publishDate;

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _jobService: JobsService, private ngbDateParserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paramsObserver = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
    let jobId = params['jobId'];
    this._jobService
     .read(jobId)
     .subscribe(
       job => {
        this.job = job;
        this.expireDate = new Date(this.job.expireDate);
        this.publishDate = new Date(this.job.publishDate);
        this.job.expireDate = { "year": this.expireDate.getFullYear(), "month": this.expireDate.getMonth(), "day": this.expireDate.getDate() } ;
        this.job.publishDate = { "year": this.publishDate.getFullYear(), "month": this.publishDate.getMonth(), "day": this.publishDate.getDate() } ;
       },
       error => this._router.navigate(['/jobs'])
     );
   });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.paramsObserver.unsubscribe();
  }

  update(form: NgForm) {
    this.job = form.value;
    let publishDate = this.job.publishDate;
    let expireDate = this.job.expireDate;
    let publishDateFormated = this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(publishDate);
    let expireDateFormated = this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(expireDate);
    this.job.publishDate = publishDateFormated;
    this.job.expireDate = expireDateFormated;
    this._jobService
      .update(this.job)
        .subscribe(savedJob => this._router.navigate(['/jobs', savedJob._id]), error => this.errorMessage = error);
 }
}
```

`parent.template.html`:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <contract-type name="contractType" [job]="job" ngModel ngDefaultControl></contract-type>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="update(myForm)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save">Save</i></button>
</form>
```

and this is my child component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { NgForm, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'contract-type',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="contractTypes">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="contractType">Contract Type</label>
      <select id="contractType" name="contractType" required [(ngModel)]="job.contractType" class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected>Select an item</option>
        <option *ngFor="let contractType of contractTypes" [value]="contractType.name_en">{{ contractType.name_en }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    `
})

export class ContractTypeComponent {
  private contractTypes;
  @Input() job;
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this._http.get('/api/contractTypes')
     .subscribe((res)=>{
       this.contractTypes = res.json();
    });
  }
}
```

my edit form with default previous data:
[image]

and if click on submit button with no click on contract type dropdown. inside post data that dropdown goes empty, but if click on that, then its selected option is posted.
[image]

Note: I'm using that child component for add purpose also, so because of reusability i have decided to make that as separate component.

and after submit its form is like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `this.job = form.value;` from parent component update function. But don't know the reason of that. Why `form.value` pass the wrong data?